# Let $p$ be a prime. Prove that $\sum_{i=0}^{p}\binom pix^i \equiv x + 1 \pmod p$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $p$ be a prime. Prove that $\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{p}\binom pix^i \equiv x + 1 \pmod p$.

i got

\begin{align}
& \frac{p!}{i!(p-i)!}(x^0+x^1+x^2+x^3+x^4+\cdots+x^p) \\[4pt]
= {} &  1\cdot (x^0 + x^1 + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 +\cdots+x^p)
\end{align}

so does $(x^0+x^1+x^2+x^3+x^4+\cdots+x^p) = x + 1 \pmod p$?!
am i on the right track here?

Comment: First check whether the sum is right. Do you mean $(a/p)$ or do you mean $(i/p)$? This looks like a Legendre symbol, Is it? It is indeed true that for most $x$ we have $1+x+x^2+\cdots +x^p\equiv x+1\pmod{p}$.

Comment: i meant to write (p/i)!

Comment: Or did you mean $\binom{p}{i}$, binomial coefficient, no bar?

Comment: yeah, thats what i meant? no bar

Comment: And you meant the sum to start at $i=0$, right?

Comment: yes, the sum to start at i=0

Comment: The binomial coefficient $\binom{p}{i}$ is divisible by $p$ except when $i=0$ and $i=p$. So our messy sum is congruent to $1+x^p$ modulo $p$. But by Fermat's Theorem $x^p\equiv x\pmod{p}$.

Comment: so 1 + x (modp) =  x + 1(modp), is that right?

Comment: Repost of this closed question: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1285866/264

Comment: Oh yes, $1+x$ is the same thing as $x+1$.

Comment: thanks for the help  André Nicolas

Comment: You are welcome. When you post questions, please indicate what you have tried. In this case, that might have helped us identify the various typos more quickly.

Comment: Another way is to note the LHS is the expansion of $(1+x)^p$, and then with Fermat"s theorem...

Answer (score 1):

All $\binom{p}{i} \equiv 0$ unless $i =0, p$ so all these terms go away from the sum only the terms that remain are 1 and $x$. Hence the result. Or by using binomial theorem we have $\sum_{i =0}^{p} \binom{p}{i}x^i=(1+x)^p$ so now by Fermat's little theorem we have $(1+x)^p \equiv (1+x)$.

Answer (score 0):

There's a difference between modular arithmetic and equality. Unless you have coded your answer improperly, you've made an error in notation:

The symbol congruence is a relation which has to do with mod n. An equals sign is a more (probably the most ubiquitous and fundamental) general relation.

Equality is reserved for more fundamental answers. Mod n deals with equivalence classes of integers and how we can partition numbers into these equivalence classes.

You probably know all of this, just want to help!